# ReSharper 10: VS2015 Pro Throws OutOfMemoryException Using "Show Type Dependecy"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I just installed **trial** ReSharper 10 on Visual Studio 2015 Pro **with Update 1**. I'm trying to create a *Type Dependency Diagram* for a large **C#** project, but it after running for a while, VS2015 throws `OutOfMemoryException`.

I believe there was a similar bug on earlier versions of VS and R#. Referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272096/resharper-throws-outofmemoryexception-on-big-solution%22here%22) StackOverflow. But the solution mentioned involves enabling large memory allocation to the Visual Studio process by executing `editbin /LARGEADDRESSAWARE devenv.exe`. I don't know if there is a known solution for this in VS2015.

**Here is the version information for ReSharper:**

> JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 10.0.2 Build 104.0.20151218.120627
> dotMemory 10.0.20151218.125655 dotTrace 10.0.20151218.132452 ReSharper
> 10.0.20151218.130009

**And for VS:**

> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.24720.00 Update
> 1 Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01055
>
> Installed Version: Professional

**Also, here is the System Info as well:**

> **OS Name**: Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
>
> **Version**: 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
>
> **Other OS Description**: Not Available
>
> **OS Manufacturer**: Microsoft Corporation
>
> **System Name**: XXXXXX
>
> **System Manufacturer**: LENOVO
>
> **System Model**: 20AQ005PUS
>
> **System Type**: x64-based PC
>
> **Processor**: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz, 2301 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
>
> **BIOS Version/Date**: LENOVO GJET67WW (2.17 ), 12/10/2013
>
> **SMBIOS Version**: 2.7
>
> **Windows Directory**: C:\Windows
>
> **System Directory**: C:\Windows\system32
>
> **Boot Device**: \Device\HarddiskVolume1
>
> **Locale**: United States
>
> **Hardware Abstraction Layer**: Version = "6.1.7601.17514"
>
> **User Name**: XXXXXXX
>
> **Time Zone**: XXXXXXX
>
> **Installed Physical Memory (RAM)**: 8.00 GB
>
> **Total Physical Memory**: 7.71 GB
>
> **Available Physical Memory**: 3.24 GB
>
> **Total Virtual Memory**: 15.4 GB
>
> **Available Virtual Memory**: 9.63 GB
>
> **Page File Space**: 7.71 GB
>
> **Page File**: C:\pagefile.sys